# Picasso in recyclerview can not auto refresh the display when complete load?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, refresh, picasso

i use picasso to display an image in recyclerview, but it won't auto refresh the item when load image complete, i have to manually scroll to make the image be displayed. What have i do to fix it, to make the item of recyclerview auto update the display when completed load?

this is my adapter class :

---

```
 public class LocationListRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView
         .Adapter<LocationListRecyclerViewAdapter
         .DataObjectHolder> {
     private static String LOG_TAG = "LocationListRecyclerViewAdapter";
     private ArrayList<LocationObject> mDataset;
     private static MyClickListener myClickListener;
     private Context mContext;
     static String imageUrls;
     public static String[] thumbnailUrl;
     private LayoutInflater inflater;


     public LocationListRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<LocationObject> mDataset) {
         this.mContext = context;
         this.mDataset = mDataset;

     }


     public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
         TextView locName;
         TextView locAddress;
         TextView locDistance;
         RoundedImageView roundedImageView;

         public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
             super(itemView);
             this.locName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_name);
             this.locAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_address);
             this.locDistance = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_distance);
             this.roundedImageView = (RoundedImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_location);

             Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
             itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
         }

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
         }
     }

     public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
         this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
     }

     public LocationListRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<LocationObject> myDataset) {
         mDataset = myDataset;
     }

     @Override
     public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                int viewType) {
         View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                 .inflate(R.layout.location_listcard_item, parent, false);

         this.mContext = parent.getContext();
         thumbnailUrl = new String[10];

         TextView locName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.location_name);
         TextView locAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.location_address);
         TextView locDistance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.location_distance);
         Typeface helvetica = Typeface.createFromAsset(parent.getContext().getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"fonts/Helvetica.otf");
         locName.setTypeface(helvetica);
         locAddress.setTypeface(helvetica);
         locDistance.setTypeface(helvetica);

         DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
         return dataObjectHolder;
     }

>     @Override
>     public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {

         LocationObject item = mDataset.get(position);

         holder.locName.setText(mDataset.get(position).getLocationName());
         holder.locAddress.setText(mDataset.get(position).getLocationAddress());
         holder.locDistance.setText(String.valueOf(mDataset.get(position).getLocationDistance())+"m");

         Log.i(position+" photos"," = "+mDataset.get(position).getLocationPhoto());

         //mContext
         Picasso.with(holder.roundedImageView.getContext()).cancelRequest(holder.roundedImageView);
         Picasso.with(holder.roundedImageView.getContext())
                 .load(mDataset.get(position).getLocationPhoto())
                 .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                 .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                 .resize(200,200)
                 .into(holder.roundedImageView);

         holder.itemView.setTag(item);

     }

     public void addItem(LocationObject dataObj, int index) {
         mDataset.add(index, dataObj);
         notifyItemInserted(index);
     }

     public void deleteItem(int index) {
         mDataset.remove(index);
         notifyItemRemoved(index);
     }


     @Override
     public int getItemCount() {
         return mDataset.size();
     }

     public interface MyClickListener {
         public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
     }


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let Picasso do its job, you do not need to interfere in the download process, the library itself knows when to cancel the request if necessary.

Always helpful before you use the library, carefully explore all of its fine points of using.
http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
    LocationObject item = mDataset.get(position);

    holder.locName.setText(item.getLocationName());
    holder.locAddress.setText(item.getLocationAddress());
    holder.locDistance.setText(String.valueOf(item.getLocationDistance())+" m");

    Picasso.with(mContext)
           .load(item.getLocationPhoto())
           .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
           .resize(200,200)
           .centerCrop()
           .into(holder.roundedImageView);
}
```

Comment: still same bro, it won't automatically refresh the item display, but when i scroll it the image chaged :/

Comment: i've remove it bro, but still not work, still wont auto update the display